# Android GPS location

Tags: android, gps, location

I'm trying to get the current location of the phone through GPS. I followed the tutorial on the Android Developer's pages ([Location and Maps](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html)) and I downloaded some examples too.

I keep getting this error in LogCat, though:

```
GPS    [assist_gps_request_set_id][line = 1197] : Failed with INVALID SET-ID TYPE
GpsLocationProvider    Error getting cell location info.
```

How can I make this error go away and let my app work?

Comment: show us please code how you do use `GpsLocationProvider`

Comment: I use the same code from the developer's pages. So I use the class LocationProvider:
LocationProvider locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);

Comment: have you requested `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission?

Comment: I didn't have the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION in the manifest. After I did this, the errors are still happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With "Error getting cell location info." Android tells you that you don't have a valid GSM signal at the moment. This error happens if this results to false:

```
(gsm_cell != null) && (phone.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM) &&
                    (phone.getNetworkOperator() != null) &&
                        (phone.getNetworkOperator().length() > 3)
```

See here in function requestRefLocation(int flags):
http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-frameworks-base/com/android/server/location/GpsLocationProvider.java.htm

Have a read on the solution of this question to understand what A-GPS is and how it helps you to get a valid GPS signal:
[Get Latitude and Longitude without inserting Sim Card and Start/Stop Gps from Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375913/get-latitude-and-longitude-without-inserting-sim-card-and-start-stop-gps-from-ap)

As for "Failed with INVALID SET-ID TYPE", you should check your program with another phone. Looks to me like you don't have a SIM-Card inserted.