# How can I use device mapping with google maps and is there any sim card required for making device

Tags: google-maps, web-applications

I want to develop on web application like GPS Vehicle tracking system. Is there any device with sim card required or how to map device with google maps?

Please help me in this.

Thanks,
satyagvns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GPS to localize your phone.

[Here is tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html)

You don;t need sim card to use localization, but if you want to use google maps, you need internet connection. Cellural or wifi

[Gps latitude and longitude withous sim card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375913/get-latitude-and-longitude-without-inserting-sim-card-and-start-stop-gps-from-ap)

Comment: Actually I dont want to use my phone. Here is the Abstract of my Project. I need to make one device and attach that device to my Car and I want to track my car in web-based-application.

Comment: Thanks for reply to my question. But Still I am blocking on one point. Please help me on this. Just now added comments to your answer

Comment: For me, you need GPS sensor and cellural connection. First to localize your car than to sen data to server.